# How to subtract the cumulative values of confirmed, recovered and deseased?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subtraction

I would like to subtract the cumulative values of confirmed, recovered and deceased. However, it does not work, Google BigQuery keeps giving me this error message [image](look at the pic). All attributes are INTEGER.

Comment: Please post the query as *text* in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.  You have mixed types in the data -- suggesting that something is wrong.

Presumably, the offending value is `cumulative_recovered` which you do not show to be an `int64`.

Comment: Ohh yeah, you are right. I got my mistake. Thanks alot!!